# Rolling Mathematics in SQL (TSQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to avoid a cursor in TSQL when doing some rolling calculations to wages over time. Bascially I've all the data to calculate the wage but I'm trying to avoid doing it RBAR.

Given:

```
DROP TABLE #SampleData

SELECT *
INTO #SampleData
FROM
(
SELECT '01/01/2010' AS WageDate, 10.00 AS BaseWage, 0.05 AS WageIncrease
UNION all
SELECT '01/01/2011' AS WageDate, 10.00 AS BaseWage, 0.25 AS WageIncrease
UNION ALL 
SELECT '01/01/2012' AS WageDate, 10.00 AS BaseWage, 0.00 AS WageIncrease
UNION All
SELECT '01/01/2013' AS WageDate, 10.00 AS BaseWage, 0.15 AS WageIncrease
) data

-- Starting Point
SELECT  * ,
BaseWage * WageIncrease AS IncreaseAmount, BaseWage + (BaseWage * WageIncrease)
FROM    #SampleData

/*
Goal Point
-------------
WageDate    BaseWage    WageIncrease    IncreaseAmount
01/01/2010  10.00       0.05            0.5000
01/01/2011  10.50       0.25            2.5000
01/01/2012  13.125      0.00            0.0000
01/01/2013  13.125      0.15            1.5000
*/
```

Thoughts on how to proceed?

Comment: Search for t-sql running total query on here. Look for answers using a CTE. There are loads of 'em.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughts.  From my research so far it seems rolling totals require some aggregation function to work. I'll look more into CTEs for this per your suggestion.

Comment: SQL Server 2012 can do this quite easily using window functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012, you would just use a cumulative sum function:

```
SELECT  *,
       BaseWage * WageIncrease AS IncreaseAmount,
       BaseWage * exp(sum(log(1 + WageIncrease)) over (order by WageDate))
FROM    #SampleData
```

This implements a `product` aggregation function using logs and exponentiation.

In earlier versions, you can do the same thing with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT  *,
       BaseWage * WageIncrease AS IncreaseAmount,
       (select sd.BaseWage * exp(sum(log(1 + sd1.WageIncrease))) 
        from #SampleData sd1
        where sd1.WageDate <= sd2.WageDate
       )
FROM    #SampleData sd;
```

Comment: Perfect! That's what was missing, the product aggregation approach. Thank you, sir.